# 'Object Expected' error in IE8 [JavaScript]

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer-8, object-expected

I keep getting an 'Object expected' error in IE8, works fine in Chrome & Firefox. The error points to this bit of script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var oEdit1 = new InnovaEditor("oEdit1");
        oEdit1.REPLACE("Description");
</script>
```

I also get the same exception when debugging in Visual Studio. I'm not sure if its related but this is what it points to:

```
this.arrParagraph = [
    [getTxt("Heading 1"), "H1"],
    [getTxt("Heading 2"), "H2"],
    [getTxt("Heading 3"), "H3"],
    [getTxt("Heading 4"), "H4"],
    [getTxt("Heading 5"), "H5"],
    [getTxt("Heading 6"), "H6"],
    [getTxt("Preformatted"), "PRE"],
    [getTxt("Normal (P)"), "P"],
    [getTxt("Normal (DIV)"), "DIV"]
];
```

The code above was found in the InnovaStudio WYSIWIG Editor source files. I read elsewhere that `type="text/javascript"` should be replaced with `language="javascript"` and tried it out but doesn't work. Any ideas?

**EDIT** Here's the initializing script for InnovaEditor:

```
        edtCnt = document.createElement("DIV");
        edtCnt.id = "innovaeditor" + i;

        txt.parentNode.insertBefore(edtCnt, txt);

        window["oEdit"+i] = new InnovaEditor("oEdit"+i);

        var objStyle;
        if( window.getComputedStyle ) {
          objStyle = window.getComputedStyle(txt,null);
        } else if( txt.currentStyle ) {
          objStyle = txt.currentStyle;
        } else {
          objStyle = {width:window["oEdit"+i].width, height:window["oEdit"+i].height};
        }

        window["oEdit"+i].width=objStyle.width;
        window["oEdit"+i].height=objStyle.height;

        if(opt) {
          for(var it in opt) {
            window["oEdit"+i][it] = opt[it];
          }
        }

        window["oEdit"+i].REPLACE(txt.id, "innovaeditor" + i);          

    }    

  };
```

Comment: You may need to update your version of JQuery in the project and/or remove old versions of it still hanging around in your Scripts folder. While I'm not familiar with the Innova Editor, I have seen similar problems with other JQuery based controls.

Comment: Guess that might help. I'm using the default version provided in MVC which is 1.7.1 - I know, ancient right? Though Innova runs on pure JavaScript, sure gave me a tough time trying to get it running side by side with jQuery.

Comment: I tried upgrading to a newer version of jQuery but still no dice. I've looked at the error again & it keeps referring to the 'new InnovaEditor("oEdit1");' line. I'm not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: Any other suggestions? I'm really running out of ideas here.

Comment: Did you also delete the older versions of JQuery in the Scripts folder?

Comment: Yes I did delete them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! Turns out I had to place everything in the Scripts folder to get it working. Thanks for the help anyway.